# If $(X_n)$ are Poisson independent and $\mathbb{E}[S_n]\to+\infty$ then $\frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E}[S_n]} \rightarrow 1$ almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

> Let $X_n$ be independent Poisson random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = \lambda_n$. Define $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$. Show that if
>   $\sum \lambda_n = +\infty$, then $\frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E}[S_n]} \longrightarrow 1$ a.s.

How to prove this?

My attempt is to show, first, that $\frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E}[S_n]} \longrightarrow 1$ in probability and then show that $\frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E}[S_n]} \longrightarrow 1$ a.s.

Comment: Regarding your attempt, $E[Y_n]=1$ for all $n$ and $var(Y_n)=(E[S_n])^{-2}(Var(S_n))=(E[S_n])^{-1}\to 0$, writing $S_n/E[S_n]$ as $Y_n$. So you have L2 convergence and in particular convergence in probability. You could also use chebychev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses SLLN and the additive property of the Poisson distribution.

Let $(N_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Poisson process of unit rate. Then by the SLLN, together with the inequality

$$ \frac{N_{[t]}}{[t]+1} \leq \frac{N_t}{t} \leq \frac{N_{[t]+1}}{[t]}, $$

it is easy to check that $N_t / t \to 1$ as $t \to \infty$ a.s. Now let $T_k = \lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_k$. Then $T_k \to \infty$ and hence $ N_{T_k} / T_k \to 1$.

Finally, notice that the distribution of the process $(S_n : n \geq 1)$ is identical to the distribution of the process $(N_{T_k} : k \geq 1)$. Therefore $S_n / \Bbb{E}S_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ a.s.

Comment: How do you suggest to apply the "sledgehammer" method, since $S_n/E(S_n)$ is not a sum $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ with $(X_k)$ independent?

Comment: *Kai Lai Chung* with a K.

Comment: @Did, I cannot believe what I have done there :( I haven't been doing math for about two weeks, and I must have lost some of my mathematical ability. Thank you, I will wipe that out.

Comment: No problem. $ $